# Word problem that I need help explaining! Can someone break this down for me?

Tags: word-problem

There are $32$ students in Mrs. Vicky’s class. Some of the students took one pencil each from the box with pencils on the teachers desk. Then a third of the remaining students took $3$ pencils each, and there were no more pencils left in the box. How many pencils were there in the box at first?

I’m sure there is a super simple answer for this and I’m embarrassed that I can’t explain it myself! Please help!

Comment: The usual first step is to assign variables to the relevant unknowns and then to write the given and desired information in terms of these variables.

Comment: As far as the pencils are concerned, "a third of the remaining students took 3 pencils each" amounts to the same as "all the remaining students took one pencil each."

Comment: Thank you Andreas! “amounts to the same as "all the remaining students took one pencil each."  This is what I was missing when I was trying to work out the equation.  For some reason I was thinking that not all students maybe took a pencil. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: Andreas Blass  had it right but, not that it's important, "How do you get one third of 32 students???" :)

Answer (score 0):

I’ll give you a road map for a straightforward algebraic solution, though the problem can be solved without algebra using the hint given by **Andreas Blass** in the comments. Let $s$ be the number of students who took one pencil each, and let $p$ be the total number of pencils.

- In terms of $s$, how many students took $3$ pencils each?
- Again in terms of $s$, how many pencils did those students take altogether?

Now write down an expression in terms of $s$ for the total number of pencils taken by *all* of the students who took pencils. Simplify that expression. How is it related to $p$?